# char array returning value like 50'w'

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, char

Language =C#
Software = Visual Studio 2015

While writing program to find sum of integers in given string I am facing issue.
while fetching each character from string I am getting value like `87'W',101'e'` instead of `'w'` ,`'e'`. (showing respective integer of char also which is not required)

Program:

```
public static void Main()     
{     
     string s = "Welcome to 2018";     
     int sumofInt = 0;     
       for (int i = 0; i < s.Length; i++)     
       {     
           if (Char.IsDigit(s[i]))     
           {     
               sumofInt += Convert.ToInt32(s[i]);     
           }     
       }     
    Console.WriteLine(sumofInt);     

}
```

expected o/p = **11**
actual o/p = **203**

here for `s[i]` values are coming as e.g `50'2'`

### is there any way to avoid this numeric representation of charater (50 , 87 etc) ? ?? (without trimming)

Comment: `int sum = s.Where(c => c >= '0' && c <= '9').Sum(c => c - '0');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:-you are getting the ASCII representation of the char as an integer

```
public static void Main()     
{     
     string s = "Welcome to 2018";     
     int sumofInt = 0;     
       for (int i = 0; i < s.Length; i++)     
       {     
           int val = (int)Char.GetNumericValue(s[i]);
           if (Char.IsDigit(val))     
           {     
               sumofInt += Convert.ToInt32(val);     
           }     
       }     
    Console.WriteLine(sumofInt);     

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The typical trick for `'0'..'9'` range is to subtract `'0'`:

```
char digit = '7';
int value = digit - '0';
```

You can simplify your code with a help of *Linq*:

```
public static void Main() {
  string s = "Welcome to 2018";     

  int sumofInt = s.Sum(c => c >= '0' && c <= '9' // do we have digit?
    ? c - '0'                                    // if true, take its value
    : 0);                                        // else 0

  Console.WriteLine(sumofInt);
}
```